# Creating a template class: losing images and style by changing directory of template files

Tags: php, html, template-engine

I'm writing a template engine for a already waited template.

Now before you say about how redounded this is. I get payed to do it and I don't know why they insist to have one of their own (probably because template is already been done and they have marked it).

They've already marked the template like this:

index.html

```
<html>
<head><title> [title] </title></head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<body>
<img class="header" src="images/header.jpg" />
[contents]
</body>

</html>
```

I'm using a very simple find&replace approach and it works good enough:

index.php

```
$e = new tengine ;
$e->load_template('index.html');// basically file_get_contents 

$e->replace('title' , 'zzzzzzz'); 

$e->replace( 'contents' , 'xxxx');

$e->show();
```

It works fine while they are in the same directory.

Now I want to move my assets to another directory called templates.

So I have to call my template like this:

```
index.php

    $e->load_template('template/index.html');
```

Now the page that renders the template (index.php) is not in the same directory as template file (index.html).

It's still works but I loss all the style and images and .js that are in the template page  because they are in the template directory and I render the page one directory above them.

Are there any workarounds? Have in mind that template is already done and creating some kind of GLOBAL `base_url` like and changing all images and .js/.css links is out of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also suggest creating a .htaccess file rewriting every request to the "templates/" subdirectory except if the requested file exists (so index.php or other files in the webroot still get served properly):

Enable "mod_rewrite" for apache2. At the shell type:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Put a file named ".htaccess" in the root directory of your web-application with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the requested file does not exist redirect it to the "template/" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ template/$1 [L]
```

Now if you reqest "css/style.css" the "RewriteCond" statements will notice that there is no "css/style.css" and rewrite the request to "template/css/style.css". But if you request "index.php" the rewrite conditions will notice that there is a file with such a name and serve it like usually.

Comment: thankx good idea , but if a image is linked like `src="../../images/x.jpg"` i would end up with `"template/../../images/x.jpg"` ?

Comment: You wrote that you moved the template (and all it's associated content) into a subfolder "template/" The above rewrite takes care of this.

If you added links to new images like "../../images/x.jpg" you were not true when writing "no modifications to the template" ... But I am so kind to overlook this :)

Every link which works when the template gets called directly in the "template/" subdirectory will also work when the template gets called via index.php.

So "../../images/x.jpg" will of course yield "template/../../images/x.jpg" which will get resolved to "../images/x.jpg" of the root path.

Comment: thanks for your kindness :)  however all the images are in the image directory => in the template directory ... and there might me some sub directories in the template directory .. like sidebars which contains user_sidebar.php and images are linked in it like "../img/x.jpg" .... any way it doesn't matter , thanks for the answer

Comment: anyways ... you are asking about a relative path. I can't say anything about this as long as I don't know from where the request to ../../images/x.jpg originated. The translation of a relative into an absolute path is usually done by the browser. So if you request "../../images/x.jpg" from within a file served as "/company/aboutus/index.html" then the request which is seen by apache will be to "/images/x.jpg" because the relative/absolute path translation is already done by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Just use absolute paths to your media files instead of relative. So, rather than  using something like

```
 <img src='../assets/img/temp.png' />
```

or

use

```
 <img src='/assets/img/temp.png' />
```

and

Then it no longer matters at all where your processing occurs, where your templates sit, from what server-dir the file is called, etc. You can shift them around to your heart's content, it won't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use rewrite engine using .htaccess

For example create a rewrite rule for css folder and address it to http://www.mysite.com/css/.

With rewrite module i'm sure you can somehow handle it.

Answer (score 1):

what about
    dirname(**FILE**).'/example.php';

with dirname file you are at exactly that place where the file is

Comment: i'm sorry i don't see how `dirname` can help me ? you se when i get contents of template , all the images are linked relative to that template like 'src="images/header.jpg"` , but when i show/render template i'm doing it in another directory above the template so 'src="images/header.jpg"` should change to 'src="template/images/header.jpg"` or the picture wouldn't appear

Comment: change src="/path/to/img/folder/img.jpg" like that with the first / you start from the root directory then its all good as long as you dont change the img folder path

Comment: it does work if you try it like that on a server. you could also do src="http://www.yourdomain.com/pathToImgFolder/image.jpg" but I prefer the first slash and always point like that from root

Comment: thank you , but as i'v said in my question i don't want to change the template ( it's links ) cuz it's already done and it would take a long time to change them all ... i know absolute path is the answer but it's too late for that .

Answer (score 1):

It's because the 'css' directory is in the template direcotory, and the browser can not access it.
put the 'css' directory in the view directory or use צore accurate address.

Comment: all the links are relative  , so it doesn't matter where i put the css directory .

Answer (score 1):

If it is an option to modify the html head of the template(s) you can use the **base** tag to change the base url of all relative URLs in the document:

```
<head>
<base href="http://yourdomain/template/">
...
</head>
```

Just remember to insert it right at the top before any relative path is used.

Comment: thanx , it's good solution but then again i have to change the relative links in template too .

Answer (score 1):

In HTML there is a simple hack available to do the things you needed. The hack is through base url, you have to add extra tag link as:

```
<head>
      <base href="domin.com/directory">
</head>
```

Kindly Note everything has its pro and cons using the base html tag

Pro:

- No use of .htaccess
- No use of copying files
- Static representation of the document

cons:

- It will link all the href tags to the base href provided including Anchor, link or any thing using href

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, that asset inclusion should be done by your templating engine, too.

So instead of writing

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in you template, do something like this

```
[stylesheet css/style.css]
```

and in your engine then create the appropriate HTML with your prepended asset path.
OR you copy the css files in a relative directory to the root directory.

Comment: thankyou , great idea but unfortunately there are lots of images in the pages and they have the same problem .... im going to this for css file though !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the links of the template is the problem since it does not access the .css/.js from the template directory.
What matters here is the location of the file rendering them, since the links would then be read after it is rendered.
So as long as the index.php is on the same directory as before, the links in the template should still work fine.